# Making objects of different classes interact?

Tags: processing

I am creating a simple program in processing in which there is a ball bouncing around the screen and there is also Kirby who is able to blink and move around the screen. What I want is for the program to detect whenever the ball is touching Kirby so that Kirby can blink as a response, however, Kirby and the Ball are of two different classes. How do I make this work?

```java
Kirby k;
Ball b;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  k = new Kirby(width/2, height/2);
  b = new Ball(2);
}

void draw() {
  background(60, 190, 255);
  k.display();
  k.blink();
  b.display();
  b.move();
}

void keyPressed() {
  k.move();
}

class Ball{
  float x = width/4;
  float y = height/4;
  float rb = 30;
  float xspeed = (random(-5, 5));
  float yspeed = (random(-5, 5));

  Ball(int stemp){
    xspeed = xspeed + stemp;
    yspeed = yspeed + stemp;
  }

  void display(){
    fill(0);
    ellipse(x, y, rb, rb);
  }

  void move(){
    x = x + xspeed;
    y = y + yspeed;
    if (y > height || y < 0){
      yspeed *= -1;
    }
    if (x > width || x < 0){
      xspeed *= -1;
    }
  }
}

class Kirby {
  float xpos;
  float ypos;
  float rk = 100;
  float eye = 30;
  float mov = 5;

  Kirby(int xtemp, int ytemp) {
    xpos = xtemp;
    ypos = ytemp;
  }


  void display() {  
    noStroke();
    fill(225, 100, 190);
    ellipse(xpos, ypos, rk, rk);
    fill(0);
    ellipse(xpos - 20, ypos - 10, 10, eye);
    ellipse(xpos + 20, ypos - 10, 10, eye);
  }

  void blink() {
    if (mousePressed == true) {
      eye = 1;
    } else {
      eye = 30;
    }
  }

  void move() {
    if (keyPressed == true) {
      if (key == 'w') {
        ypos = ypos - mov;
      } else if (key == 'a') {
        xpos = xpos - mov;
      } else if (key == 's') {
        ypos = ypos + mov;
      } else if (key == 'd') {
        xpos = xpos + mov;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should add the relevant language tag to your question so people can find it.

Comment: Since the `Ball` and the `Kirby` don't know about each other -- and probably shouldn't -- it falls mostly to the main application to perform the collision detection, and to make the `Kirby` blink when needed.  It looks like the most appropriate place to hook that in would be the main class's `draw()` method.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Please notice the [tag:processing] tag. Processing is a language.

Comment: I did.  Never heard of that one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though your data is represented by two classes, you can still access that data from your main sketch. Here's a smaller example:

```java
PVector circleOne;
PVector circleTwo;
float circleSize = 100;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  circleOne = new PVector(width/2, height/2);
  circleTwo = new PVector(0, 0);
}

void draw() {
  background(64);
  circleTwo.set(mouseX, mouseY);

  float distance = dist(circleOne.x, circleOne.y, circleTwo.x, circleTwo.y);
  if (distance < circleSize) {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
  } else {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
  }

  ellipse(circleOne.x, circleOne.y, circleSize, circleSize);
  ellipse(circleTwo.x, circleTwo.y, circleSize, circleSize);
}
```

This code uses two instances of the `PVector` class to represent two circles, and it gets their `x` and `y` to check whether they're touching, using [circle-circle collision detection](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection).

You would want to do something very similar, just using your classes instead of the `PVector` class.

You could also move the distance check to inside one of the classes, which is actually what `PVector` does:

```java
PVector circleOne;
PVector circleTwo;
float circleSize = 100;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  circleOne = new PVector(width/2, height/2);
  circleTwo = new PVector(0, 0);
}

void draw() {
  background(64);
  circleTwo.set(mouseX, mouseY);

  float distance = circleOne.dist(circleTwo);
  if (distance < circleSize) {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
  } else {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
  }

  ellipse(circleOne.x, circleOne.y, circleSize, circleSize);
  ellipse(circleTwo.x, circleTwo.y, circleSize, circleSize);
}
```